# Unable to connect bluetooth keyboard on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, bluetooth

So I bought the Microsoft Surface Keyboard(bluetooth) and a USB bluetooth dongle(Hama 49218), but I can't get windows to detect the keyboard at all.

I can use the keyboard with my ipad and phone, and I can see the pad and phone(and my neighbors stuff) in windows, but I can't see the keyboard in windows.

Everything seems to work fine except for the windows - keyboard combo.

Please help, I'm going crazy.

Comment: By any chance, did you use the [add device wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15290/windows-connect-bluetooth-device)? "View devices" only shows those that were already connected before.

Comment: Yes, that is how I have been able to see other devices.

Comment: And you are sure no additional driver is required for the Windows?

Comment: I'm not sure. I can't find anything thought. I should be able to detect it without any specific drivers right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the dongle(Hama 49218) is imcompatible with the Surface Keyboard. I can't find any one else confirming this, but changing to a different make of dongle(Belkin Mini bluetooth v4.0) solved the issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Win 10 then you don't need a driver (according to Microsoft support https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/problem-with-hama-bluetooth-usb-adapter-drivers/3ea1ee2b-5569-4f22-b7ee-23128ba7c933) but you should uninstall all other BT software. Earlier Windows need a driver. Various places offer a driver but strangely Hama do not that I can find. Google "Hama 49218 driver" for driver downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Just another data point. I'm able to use the Microsoft Surface Keyboard on Windows 7 with a Rosewill RNX-BT402 bluetooth adapter. Just had to make sure I installed the drivers from the Rosewill website.

Officially, Microsoft does not state compatibility with Windows 7.

edit 1: If the keyboard does not respond, try turning off the bluetooth adapter by right clicking on bluetooth icon -> open settings (not Turn off adapter) -> put checkmark on Turn off bluetooth adapter -> OK. Then right click bluetooth adapter -> Turn on. Try keyboard again.

edit 2: FYI there are many WIDCOMM driver versions. You must have the WIDCOMM driver package installed, as it starts the bluetooth service. Just having the driver for the adapter (Broadcom BCM20702) alone is not enough.